# Required to export all page records in angular slickgrid export option

Tags: angular, export-to-excel, slickgrid

I am using angular slickgrid for showing my data with pagination. Assume that i am having 1000 record totally and showing 100 records in each page by using pagination concept. While exporting records from first page, it exports only first page records. I want to download total records of slickgrid if i am in any of the page. How can i achieve this.

My code

```
exportExcel() {
    var options = {
        filename: "Data Export",
        format: FileType.xlsx
    }

    this.angularGrid.excelExportService.exportToExcel(options).catch(error => {
        this.showAlert(error.message);
        return error;
    });
}
```

**Software Version**

Angular : 7.3.5

Angular-Slickgrid : 2.17.10

TypeScript : 3.1.6

Operating System : Windows 10

Node : 10.16.3

NPM : 6.9.0

Comment: You can only export current page, it's by design and I won't change that. If you want to export everything, you'll need to change your page size. The Export Service loops through the DataView dataset and when you use pagination then you only have a subset in the DataView, which is the current page, so that is what you get in the export.

Comment: Thank you @ghiscoding